# Marketing Cloud SQL If Statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I want to assign a Yes or No to a column based on if another variable is Blank or not.

Would it be something like this?

> if OpenedDate is Empty then
>
> > set Opened = No
> >
> > > > if OpenedDate is NotEmpty then
> > > >
> > > > > set Opened = Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [CASE statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in order to accomplish this. So something like:

```
CASE WHEN OpenedDate IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS 'Opened'
```

Comment: Says there is an error near the 'AS".

Comment: Case When o.EventDate is Null THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' AS 'Open',

Comment: The above is missing 'END'. Just tested this statement and it resolves just fine on my end.

Comment: Haha. I also just added it and it worked.

Comment: Case When o.EventDate is Null THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS 'Open' ,